# ReactJS pass to onClick function current div ID

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
export default React.createClass({
displayName: 'Test',

getInitialState() {
    return {
        activeItem: 0,
    };
},

onItemClick(item) {
    this.setState({
        activeItem: item
    });
},

isActive(item) {
    return item === this.state.activeItem;
},

render() {
    var circle = {
        'one': {
            items: []
        }
    };

    ['one'].forEach((k, i) => {
        for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
            var itemNo = (i * 10 + j);
            var itemClasses = c('item', 'item-' + itemNo, {
                'selected': this.isActive(itemNo)
            });

            var item = React.DOM.div({
                key: "item" + itemNo,
                className: itemClasses,
                onClick: () => this.onItemClick(itemNo)
            }, itemNo);
            circle[k].items.push(item);
        }
    });


    return ( 
      <div>{circle.one.items}</div>
    );
}
});
```

The `circle.one.items` array is being populated by **dynamically** generated divs and should contain:

```
<div class="item item-1">1</div>
<div class="item item-2">2</div>
<div class="item item-3">3</div>
```

No matter what div I click on, only the 3rd one gets selected because `itemNo` last value is 3.

Look at: `onClick: () => this.onItemClick(itemNo)`. This is wrong. How can I pass the ID of the div I'm clicking to `onItemClick()`?

Answer (score 1):

You are having a `closure issue`, by the way, a quick fix is to change the `for`statement with a function iteration:

```js
var circle = {
  'one': {
    items: [1, 2, 3].map((item, index, array) => React.DOM.div({
      onclick: () => console.log('clicked at', index, item);
    }))
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the closure issue hint.

Answer (score -1):

After reading [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), the simplest fix is to use `let`. I just changed `var itemNo = (i * 10 + j);` with `let itemNo = (i * 10 + j);`.

Comment: `let` has no effect in your case, your bug depends on the `asyc` execution of your `onClick` callback... when it will be fired the value of `itemNo` is always the value of the last iteration... Using a function iteration you can keep the current value across these callbacks.

Comment: Well it seems that it does have effect. Thank you.